# Alamofire Manager initialisation with Timberjack configuration and serverTrustPolicyManager not working

Tags: ssl, alamofire, swift2

I'm having a problem integrating Timberjack logging with my custom Alamofire Manager. I currently construct the Manager like this:

```
private let manager = Alamofire.Manager(serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [
    "api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: true),
    "dev.api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: false),
    "staging.api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: false)
]))
```

and my wildcard SSL certificate hostname verification is ignored on the dev.api and staging.api subdomains, as expected.

As soon as I add the configuration to support Timberjack logging to the Manager.init like this:

```
private let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: Timberjack.defaultSessionConfiguration(), serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: [
    "api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: true),
    "dev.api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: false),
    "staging.api.example.com": .PerformDefaultEvaluation(validateHost: false)
]))
```

the default serverTrustPolicyManager seems to be used, and the SSL handshake with dev.api and staging.api fail, because they don't match the *.example.com SSL certificate hostname. It's like something is overwriting my ServerTrustPolicyManager.

My manager is a declared inside my API class, which is a singleton, so I'm sure it's not a weak reference problem. Also, if it was, my first code block wouldn't work.

```
@objc class API : NSObject {
    static let api = API()
    private let manager = ... // as above
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As a start, could you remove `Timberjack` and just use a `NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()` and give it a try? If that works, then you know you have an issue in your `Timberjack` configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @cnoon. I've done as you suggested and it does indeed appear to be a Timberjack issue.

Comment: Excellent. At least you're tracking it down! If you want to post the Timberjack configuration logic here in your question, we could continue to help you investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help! Here is the Timberjack issue: https://github.com/andysmart/Timberjack/issues/3 There is no config I'm using for Timberjack.